# date-picker vuefify vue3 does not show above text field

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use date-picker when I clic a text field, but when I clic on the text-field date picker appears on the top of my browser not above the text-field.

I appreciate your help

```
    <v-col cols="12" md="3">
      <v-menu
        v-model="menu1"
        :close-on-content-click="true"
        transition="scale-transition"
        
        min-width="auto"
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="reporte.fechadeinicio"
            label="Fecha de inicio"
            prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
            readonly
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="{ click: cambiarEstadoDeMenu1 }"
          ></v-text-field>
        </template>
        <v-date-picker
        
          v-model="reporte.fechadeinicio"
          
        ></v-date-picker>
      </v-menu>
    </v-col>
```

I need date-picker appears above text field

Comment: is this vuetify3?  [v-menu](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#usage) activator slot doesn't provide `on` or `attrs` anymore, it's just `props`.  Should be `<template v-slot:activator="{ props }">`, then on your text field `v-bind="props"`.  Using correct activator code and vuetify3 I'm unable to reproduce.  Menu shows up on top of the text field.